# .NET Core 3 returns -0 string when a near 0 negative number is rounded

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

So this odd behavior was caught during a unit test we were implementing.

In .NET Core 3.x, if a near 0 negative number is rounded and then converted to a string, the string will display "-0" instead of 0.

Framework and .NET Core 2.x don't exhibit this behavior.

```cs
double d = -.1;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(d,0));
```

[.NET Core Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uv3rBz)

[Framework Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dtK0pM)

Is this a new bug within Core, or some strange intended change?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32237

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a breaking change in .NET Core 3.0, for consistency between languages and IEEE-754 compliance.

Quoting from [Floating-Point Parsing and Formatting improvements in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/):

> *ToString(), ToString("G"), and ToString("R") will now return the shortest roundtrippable string.*

The emphasis in the above is on "*roundtrippable*". Before this change, the negative zero "-0" did not roundtrip correctly, which was fixed by the combination of [Fixing up the Double/Single parsing code to be correct #20707](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/20707) and [Roundtrip string format for single/double doesn't roundtrip -0 #9883](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/9883).

Comment: but logically -0 and 0, both are same

Comment: @viveknuna In a sense, yes, but in floating point math `1 / 0.0 = ∞` while `1 / -0.0 = -∞`. This is actually the very example given in the last link. See [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) and [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) for more on that.

Comment: great didn't know this before

Comment: Something tells me this is going to catch a lot of people. I kind of find it poor that such a change would be made without a simple method to override considering how long .NET has been around now. It's going to make porting existing code a nightmare as application users may now be faced with -0's all over the place.

Comment: @Tronald True, and also true that it may please others who would have complained about the old behavior. That's unavoidable with breaking changes. As to how wide an impact, that I don't know and can't guess. Yours looks to be the first question about it on SO, if that's any indication, and it's been more than a year since the Core 3 previews..