# Why do I get a negative zero double from this code?

Tags: c#, .net, double, .net-5

We've upgraded our application to net5.0, from netstandard2.0. When I'm trying to format double value, that is result of multiplication equals 0. Then after calling string.Format, we'are getting result "-0.00"

```
double value1 = -18234.32;
double value2 = 0.00;

var result = value1 * value2;
var stringResult = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.00}", result);
var zeroResult = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.00}", value2);

Console.WriteLine($"Value1: {value1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Value2: {value2}");

Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
Console.WriteLine($"StringResult: {stringResult}");
Console.WriteLine($"ZeroResult: {zeroResult}");
```

And the result id:

```
Value1: -18234,32
Value2: 0
Result: -0
StringResult: -0.00
ZeroResult: 0.00
```

Have you got any idea how to fix it? For now we've got workaround to change "-0.00" value to "0.00", but I'd like to now why is this happening.

Comment: You are aware that `double` does have the concept of a negative zero, aren't you?

Comment: Possibly related to this change from .NET Core 3.0: [Floating-Point Parsing and Formatting improvements in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/)

Comment: [WiredUK commented on 17 Feb 2020](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29157#issuecomment-587067587): *Does this change also cover `(-0.1M).ToString("0")` evaluating as `-0` when it was just `0` before Core 3?*

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did not know about that, thanks!

Comment: @RichardDeeming Thanks for link, it is related to this change. But in the post i see, that I have to make a workaround. Is there any global fix to use in our project?

Comment: There's [another reference to this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62768234/124386), but no workaround. You can test for `-0` by checking `result == 0D && double.IsNegative(result)`, or `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(result) == long.MinValue`, so maybe you could use that to strip out `-0`?